# iOS 13 - Buggy Large Title UINavigationBar while pushing

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar, ios13, preferslargetitles

With the iOS 13 update, I've got an annoying bug that I still wasn't able to solve when I have the `prefersLargeTitles = true` on my `UINavigationBar` and I perform a push segue.
Plus, even if I'm not 100% sure if it's related to it, my view controller has a collection view embedded.

Anyway the bug/glitch I'm talking about is the following:

[image]

Basically the text doesn't animate as I would expect when I'm pushing, and it continues to stay there till the new screen is presented. Any tips? Thanks

Comment: I think the new settings of standardAppearance, compactAppearance and scrollEdgeAppearance will help you.

Comment: I'm using them already :/ 
But maybe I missed something though... I'll dive deeper in the docks then, thanks for tip

Comment: Having the same problem. Back navigation ( pop ) animation works fine tho.

Comment: Does the pushed view controller also show large titles? Did you set its `largeTitleDisplayMode` to `never`?

Comment: Yes... The pushed view controller (Detail) doesn't have large titles, and even by setting the `largeTitleDisplayMode` to `never` in the DetailViewController, I don't get any improvement

Comment: have you found any solution? i'm at page 20 on google/stackoverflow, and nothing, even morningswiftui.com/… isn't working

Comment: @AlessandroFrancucci it didn't work for me too

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had the same issue. Try to set `navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode` to `.always` for your first VC and then `.never` for your second VC **with** `prefersLargeTitles = true` in **both** cases.

The reason is written from Apple Doc:

> If the prefersLargeTitles property of the navigation bar is false, this property has no effect and the navigation item’s title is always displayed as a small title.

Which is causing the animation glitch, and it's not a iOS13 bug only, on iOS12/11 it's already the case it's just the other way around (the animation glitch is happening when dismissing from the secondVC back to the firstVC).

I wrote an article that explain a bit more about this:
https://www.morningswiftui.com/blog/fix-large-title-animation-on-ios13

Comment: it didn't work for me, the page transition still keeping the large title and disappear without animation

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `largeTitleDisplayMode` param inside `viewWillAppear()` method.

for the base VC set it to `.always` and in the destination VC set it to `.never`

```
BASE VC

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
}


DESTINATION VC

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
 }
```